# How to do post-matching filter in webflux?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux

As we know, in jersey we have pre-matching filter and post-matching filter.

I'm wondering how can I get similar behavior with WebFilter in webflux application.

It seems the WebFilter is sort of like a pre-matching filter which will be executed for sure, no matter a resource in @RestController found or not.

My filter like this (copied from metrics filter in spring actuator):

```
@Component
@Order(100)
public class AppFilter1 implements WebFilter {

@Override
public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {

    return chain.filter(exchange).compose((call) -> filter(exchange, call));
}

private Publisher<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, Mono<Void> call) {

    System.out.println("Start AppFilter1 in thread:" + Thread.currentThread().getId() + "..........");
    ServerHttpResponse response = exchange.getResponse();
    return call.doOnSuccess((done) -> success(exchange)).doOnError((cause) -> {
        if (response.isCommitted()) {
            error(exchange, cause);
        } else {
            response.beforeCommit(() -> {
                error(exchange, cause);
                return Mono.empty();
            });
        }
    });
}

private void success(ServerWebExchange exchange) {

    System.out.println("End AppFilter1 in thread:" + Thread.currentThread().getId() + "..............");

}

private void error(ServerWebExchange exchange, Throwable cause) {
    System.out.println("End AppFilter1 with Error in thread:" + Thread.currentThread().getId() + "...............");
}

}
```

Add my controller is like:

```
@RestController
public class ExampleController {

@GetMapping("/example")
public String example() {
    System.out.println("Example in thread:" + Thread.currentThread().getId());
    return "Example";
}
}
```

What I can see is the filter will be executed for sure no matter I access /example or /notexist

Actually I'd like my filter to do post-matching, only executed for /example.

To be more specific, I'd like to see console output for /example:

```
Start AppFilter1 in thread:....
Example in thread:.....
End AppFilter1 in thread:....
```

and for a not matched resource like /notexist, there's no console output at all.

Thanks

Leon

Comment: a WebFilter can do both; please complete your question and explain what you're trying to achieve, a code snippet showing what you've tried so far and why it's not the result you expected.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I just updated the question with sample code. I'm new to reactive, I guess I may use some other operator other than "compose" to achieve my goal.

Comment: without more information about the use case (what are you trying to achieve in that filter?), it's hard to give guidance about the choice of operator. For the request path part, you can check the request path and only apply your method if it matches a particular path.

Comment: I just want to do something before /example, but I don't want my biz logic gets executed for an non-existing resource like /abcd. Checking request path in filter might not be a good idea since I may have hundreds of resource mappings. Here, pre-matching means "no matter resource matches or not, do something", post-matching means "Only when resource matches, do something".

Comment: The expect execution sequence:  pre-matching fitler --- > locate a resource   ----- > post-matching filter ----- > executed the matched resource. If no resource matched, the post-matching filter should not be invoked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Spring WebFlux `WebFilter` class does not operate at the same level as the pre/post matching filters in Jersey. It's actually closer to a Servlet filter.

The `WebFilter` has no clue about what is handling the request - it could be a Controller, a handler serving static resources, or any other custom handler.

Since you're at the HTTP level here, you can just check for the request path and whether the response status is not "404 Not Found".

Since your question does not provide much background about what you're trying to achieve here (business logic? authentication? logging? tracing? any operation that involves I/O?), I can't really say more about the choice of Reactor operator.

If you'd like a filter that only operates on Resources (as in Jersey Resources), then `WebFilter` is not the right choice as it's operating at a lower level (all HTTP exchanges). I don't think there's infrastructure for that in Spring Framework. Feel free to open an enhancement request in Spring Framework (this time providing enough details about your use case).

Comment: Thanks for the reminder of servlet filter. It seems servlet filter does not have "post-matching" concept either. The real use case could be something costly like authentication. For example, I don't want to pay extra cost to authenticate those malformed/404/robot request. Another example could be using WebFilter to provide some context data for later use, and the same, it's not worth doing something in advance if 404

Comment: I just found 1 example from other's code which is to create context property ahead with WebFilter, before the real service impl use it: https://github.com/rstoyanchev/context-holder/blob/master/src/main/java/com/example/context/RequestContextFilter.java , my concern is if a 404 request comes in, is the WebFilter paying a wasting effort?

Comment: I use a reactor version `3.2.0` with spring boot `2.1.0` and a `contextStart` method from `https://github.com/rstoyanchev/context-holder/blob/master/src/main/java/com/example/context/RequestContextFilter.java` is not available. Is this capability of holding request context data during a request lifecycle already released?

My want to use webfilter for logging purpuse to hold request context information .

Comment: @nanachimi please ask another question, comments aren't tailored for that