# How to intercept all outgoing HTTP requests formed using WebClient/WebFlux?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I have two services (A and B) running and I form HTTP Requests using WebClient in service A to connect to service B. I want to intercept the outgoing requests to log them. I cannot intercept at the entry point of service B as it is owned by another team.

I can add ExchangeFilterFunction while building the WebClient, but is there a way like how WebFilter works (keeping the filter logic separate from application code; it intercepts all incoming requests without application code changes)

I am trying something similar to [How to do post-matching filter in webflux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50559991/how-to-do-post-matching-filter-in-webflux)

I do not find any solution for it.

Comment: well if you didn't find it, then there probably isn't so you will have to use the way the documentation tells you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the login level of **ExchangeFunctions** to **debug**.

```
logging:
  level:
   org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ExchangeFunctions: debug
```

Hope, it will help you